# require for modules in nodejs with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Following the code in server.ts:

```
const express = require('express');
const athletesRouter = require('./src/routes/athletesRouter');
```

Running `node server.ts` in the console, throws:

> Error: Cannot find module './src/routes/athletesRouter'

If I change server.ts to server.js and athletesRouter.ts to athletesRouter.js, then everything works fine.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
}
```

And this is .babelrc (although I am not sure if this is relevant):

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: node doesn't know anything about TypeScript.  compile your app to JavaScript first.  Normally running `node server.ts` would almost certainly result in a syntax error, but you got lucky because everything in your `server.ts` is actually valid JavaScript.

Comment: @DanO Thank you. I am new into typescript and had not found this issue before.

Comment: This is a step-by-step-stackoverflow question that provides clean and simple information, configuration files, and a direct question.

¿Why does it get a negative point? I want to know it in order to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this is to install [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) and then run in the console `ts-node server.ts` This npm package has to be installed globally in order to use that command.

**BELOW EXTRA INFORMATION TO EXPAND ON THIS TOPIC**

There are two scenarios:

- Development enviroment: [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) can be used to reload the server while changing code. Its [`--exec`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#running-non-node-scripts) command can be used to run `ts-node` without the need to transpile `.ts` into `.js`
- Production enviroment: `.ts` code has to be transpiled into `.js`. This can be done with `tsc` command from typescript. After that, use `node` command from nodejs.

An example of this two-scenarios approach can be found below in this `package.json` where two scripts are used:

```
"scripts": {
    "startDevelopment": "nodemon --exec ts-node server.ts",
    "startProduction": "tsc && node server.js"
  }
```